# How to find the line that splits the area into two equal parts?

Tags: calculus

> Let $R$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = \cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ and $y=x^2 -1$. The line $y=k$ splits the region $R$ into two equal parts. Find the value of $k$.

First find the area.

$$A = \int\limits_{-1}^1 \left[\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) - x^2 +1\right]\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{4}{\pi} + \frac{4}{3}$$

Not exactly sure about how to find the value of $k$, whats the next step?

---

From the wonderful answers of both [Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/341231/23662) and [DonAntonio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/341232/23662) I have figured it out.

$$\int\limits_{-\sqrt{k+1}}^{\sqrt{k+1}} \left[k-x^2+1\right]\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{A}{2}$$

$$\frac{4}{3}\left(k+1\right)^{3/2} = \frac{A}{2} $$

solve for $k$

$k\approx -0.015$

Comment: Yup @MaoYiyi, that's exactly the same answer I got. Way to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\,y=k\le 0\,$ evaluate the area between the line (above) and the parabola (below), and this must be half what you got in your original integral. If you get a valid value you're done, otherwise you'll have to assume $\,k>0\,$ and then you'll have to evaluate the area between the trigonometric function (above) and the line (below) as before...

Comment: I know that, its how to setup that integral is my problem.

Comment: I can't see why, @MaoYiyi: if $\,k\le 0\,$ then the line $\,y=k\,$ meets the parabola $\,x^2-1\,$ at the points $$x=\pm\sqrt{k+1}$$ , so you have to evaluate the integral $$\int\limits_{-\sqrt{k+1}}^{\sqrt{k+1}}(k-x^2+1)\,dx$$

Comment: In my mind I had roated the entire graph and then tried to integrate.  So I was having trouble, I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the area between the $y$ axis and each of your functions, you can see whether $k \gt 0$ or $k \lt 0$.  Assuming it is less than zero, integrate the other way $\frac A2=2\int_{-1}^k x(y) dy$ where $x(y)$ is the inverse function and I doubled the integral to cover the half on the other side of the $y$ axis.  This will give you an equation for $k$

Comment: How does one find $x\left(y\right)$?  $f\left(x\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) - x^2 + 1$ how do you find $f^{-1}\left(x\right)$

Comment: @MaoYiyi:  For $k \gt 0$ you have $y=\cos(\frac {\pi x}2)$ so $x=\frac 2 \pi \arccos y$  For $k \lt 0$ you have $y=x^2-1$ so $x=\sqrt {y+1}$

Comment: I was picturing the problem wrong.  I was thinking if I rotated it all by 90 degrees, then trying to find the integral.