# Simplifying $\lim _{x\to \sqrt{c+1}-}\left(cx+x+\frac{x^3}{3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a similiar problem as the question [How to find the line that splits the area into two equal parts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341218/302735) . I'm trying to solve this statement, but it gets quite complex.

$\lim _{x\to \sqrt{c+1}-}\left(cx+x+\frac{x^3}{3}\right)$

I plug in the value, which gives:

$c\sqrt{c+1}+\sqrt{c+1}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{c+1}\right)^3}{3}$

Which should apparently simplify to:

$\frac{4}{3}\left(c+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

I fave no idea how they did this. Any suggestions as to which steps they took would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that
$$c\sqrt{c+1}+\sqrt{c+1}=(c+1)\sqrt{c+1}=(c+1)(c+1)^{1/2}=(c+1)^{3/2}.$$

Comment: Well, that was an anti climax. I can't believe I have been staring over 45 minutes at this statement without seeing that. Thanks a lot!